# ifconfig: setifdhcp: Operation not supported

Tags: solaris, dhcp

When I try to usedhcp agent to configure interface I get

```
root@z104:~# ifconfig z104cs105 dhcp start 
ifconfig: setifdhcp: Communication with dhcpagent timed out
```

When I reconfigured my dhcp server and retry to start dhcpagent on host I get this message

```
root@z104:~# ifconfig z104cs105 dhcp start
ifconfig: setifdhcp: Operation not supported
```

`pkill dhcpagent` doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create configuration files for DHCP for your network interface:

```
touch /etc/hostname.z104cs105
touch /etc/dhcp.z104cs105
echo "solaris" > /etc/nodename
```

Also, **if you are running Solaris in KVM/qemu** (virsh/virt-manager/...), you probably need to disable x2APIC:

```
sudo virsh edit MyVirtualMachine
<cpu ...>...
    <model...
    <feature policy='disable' name='x2apic'/>
</cpu>
```

More at https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/howto-solaris-11-on-kvm/